# Show 3D elements on 2D background

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, game-design

I'll make a navigation menu in my game and had the good idee to this the enemies to start games or go to the gun store. The problem is when I look in game mode, the enemy named `ZomBear` in hierarchy and gun are away.

The `ZomBear` and the gun are 3D elements that I will show on a canvas named `StartScreen` in hierarchy. How Can I do that?

[image]
<sup>(Click on image to see full size)</sup>

Notes by the hierarchy:

- Everything that begin whit `Btn` are button elements.
- `StartScreen`, `PlayButtons` and `LevelButtons` is a panel
- `Gun` and `ZomBear` are 3D elements form the `Prefab` folder.

Here you have also a screen from aside:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify the setting on your canvas to a more desirable render mode. The canvas provides three options: screen space overlay, screen space camera and world space.

From what I understand, you would want to use world space, as it allows you to place a canvas freely in the world without it automatically obscuring the rest of the scene.

Comment: I've change the options but the best one was screen space camera, not world space like you has suggested me. But thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases 3D elements are always behind the UI elements. If you want to do so, then you have to place your background on `Quad` rather then any GUI element.

- Place a unit size `Quad`.
- Drop your image on that `Quad`.
- Resize `Quad` according to screen size.

  //*****OR*****//
- Simply place a sprite in screen.

With either of these two techniques you will achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an additional `Camera` to handle the UI 3D elements. Create a new layer (UI3D!?) and make sure your 3d ui elements uses that. Finally set the Camera to render only the new layer using the culling mask.

> Using the camera’s culling mask, you can selectively render objects which are in one particular layer. To do this, select the camera that should selectively render objects.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html